# Display ALL rows from query

Tags: mysql

My script is showing me one row, even though it should be showing 86 of them based on my results. Only 1 ID has notes associated with it.  What am I doing wrong with this query?

```
'SELECT x.*, GROUP_CONCAT(y.note ORDER BY y.note_id separator " ") as note
 from
 (
     SELECT A.* from vzw_missopportunity A
       INNER JOIN locations l ON A.Agent_ID = l.Outlet_ID
       WHERE A.Agent_ID = "'.$_SESSION['agent'].'"
       AND l.district = "'.$_SESSION['district'].'"
 ) as x
 inner join
 (

  SELECT note, note_id from notes

 ) as y on x.ID = y.note_id
 ';
```

From Print_r of query

```
SELECT x.*, GROUP_CONCAT(y.note ORDER BY y.note_id separator " ") as note from ( SELECT A.* from vzw_missopportunity A INNER JOIN locations l ON A.Agent_ID = l.Outlet_ID WHERE A.Agent_ID = "130400" AND l.district = "District 1" ) as x inner join ( SELECT note, note_id from notes ) as y on x.ID = y.note_id
```

SQL Dump

```
CREATE TABLE `notes` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `note_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `notes` (`ID`, `note_id`, `note`) VALUES
(3, '47', 'asdfasdf'),
(4, '638', 'asdfasdfasdf'),
(5, '47', 'This is a test of Notes'),
(6, '47', 'This is another Note'),
(7, '47', 'Antoher Note');


ALTER TABLE `notes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `notes`
  MODIFY `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
COMMIT;
```

The results should show all rows for the outlet ID and match the notes for that row if they exist.  Currently it is only showing the result that has notes associated with it.

missed opp table

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
-- Generation Time: Feb 25, 2020 at 10:54 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.41-MariaDB-0+deb9u1
-- PHP Version: 7.3.10-1+0~20191008.45+debian9~1.gbp365209

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


CREATE TABLE `vzw_missopportunity` (
  `Agent_ID` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `Agent_Name` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `Tran_Year` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `Tran_Period` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `Original_Mobile_ID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mobile_ID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Device_ID` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `New_Plan` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `Customer_Name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Device_Change_Date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `New_Plan_Access_Charge` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `Model` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Agent_SSO_ID` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Customer_Type` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `Previous_Plan` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Previous_Access_Charge` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(20) NOT NULL,

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `vzw_missopportunity` (`Agent_ID`, `Agent_Name`, `Tran_Year`, `Tran_Period`, `Original_Mobile_ID`, `Mobile_ID`, `Device_ID`, `New_Plan`, `Customer_Name`, `Device_Change_Date`, `New_Plan_Access_Charge`, `Model`, `Agent_SSO_ID`, `Customer_Type`, `Previous_Plan`, `Previous_Access_Charge`, `ID`, `notes`) VALUES
('123456', ' FALL RIVER', '2019', '11', '5551212555', '5551212555', '35698310000000', '13610', 'PATRICIA ', '11/11/2019', '$100.00', 'SAMSUNG GALAXY A10E', 'testuser12', 'PE', '89850', '$15.00', 1, ''),
('635987', ' NASHUA', '2019', '11', '5551212555', '5551212555', '35698310000000', '13610', 'JANET ', '11/1/2019', '$100.00', 'IPHONE 11 PURPLE 128GB VZ', 'testuser12', 'PE', '91945', '$20.00', 2, ''),
('201258', ' Westford', '2019', '12', '5551212555', '5551212555', '35698310000000', '13610', 'KIM M ', '12/23/2019', '$100.00', 'LG G7 THINQ SILVER', 'testuser12', 'PE', '94156', '$30.00', 3, ''),
('123456', ' Halifax', '2019', '12', '5551212555', '5551212555', '35698310000000', '13610', 'WILBUR L ', '12/18/2019', '$100.00', 'IPHONE XS MAX SILVER 64GB VZ', 'testuser12', 'PE', '94156', '$30.00', 4, ''),
('123456', ' Wilmington', '2019', '11', '5551212555', '5551212555', '35698310000000', '13610', 'RICHARD W ', '11/8/2019', '$100.00', 'IPHONE XR WHITE 64GB', 'testuser12', 'PE', '94156', '$30.00', 5, ''),
('123456', ' Westford', '2019', '10', '5551212555', '5551212555', '35698310000000', '13610', 'DIANE M ', '10/7/2019', '$100.00', 'IPHONE XR CORAL 64GB', 'testuser12', 'PE', '94156', '$30.00', 6, ''),
('123456', ' Halifax', '2019', '10', '5551212555', '5551212555', '35698310000000', '13610', 'KENNETH J ', '10/26/2019', '$100.00', 'KYOCERA CADENCE LTE', 'testuser12', 'PE', '94156', '$30.00', 47, ''),

ALTER TABLE `vzw_missopportunity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `vzw_missopportunity`
  MODIFY `ID` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3575;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: You have an aggregate function (group_concat) without a group by hence 1 row returned

Comment: @P.Salmon What is the best way to group the notes associated?  Prior to this it returned multiple rows with duplicate data other than the Note for that record.  I want all the notes to display on one row for that record.

Comment: You'd use a `group by` statement. Without knowing what's in `vzw_missopportunity`, we can't tell you exactly what that should look like. I'd suggest editing your post to remove the `select *` statements, and show all the selected columns explicitly.

Comment: @JoshEller I have edited my post to include that table info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group by every column in `vzw_missopportunity`, your group by statement would look like this (also note that you really only want to use `select *` for quick ad-hoc queries, and never in real code).

Edit: You mentioned you also want to see results without notes. If so, change the `inner join` on the notes table to a `left join`.

```
SELECT x.Agent_ID,
       x.Agent_Name,
       x.Tran_Year,
       x.Tran_Period,
       x.Original_Mobile_ID,
       x.Mobile_ID,
       x.Device_ID,
       x.New_Plan,
       x.Customer_Name,
       x.Device_Change_Date,
       x.New_Plan_Access_Charge,
       x.Model,
       x.Agent_SSO_ID,
       x.Customer_Type,
       x.Previous_Plan,
       x.Previous_Access_Charge,
       x.ID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(y.note ORDER BY y.note_id separator " ") as note
 from
 (
     SELECT A.Agent_ID,
            A.Agent_Name,
            A.Tran_Year,
            A.Tran_Period,
            A.Original_Mobile_ID,
            A.Mobile_ID,
            A.Device_ID,
            A.New_Plan,
            A.Customer_Name,
            A.Device_Change_Date,
            A.New_Plan_Access_Charge,
            A.Model,
            A.Agent_SSO_ID,
            A.Customer_Type,
            A.Previous_Plan,
            A.Previous_Access_Charge,
            A.ID
       from vzw_missopportunity A
       INNER JOIN locations l ON A.Agent_ID = l.Outlet_ID
       WHERE A.Agent_ID = "'.$_SESSION['agent'].'"
       AND l.district = "'.$_SESSION['district'].'"
 ) as x
 left join
 (

  SELECT note, note_id from notes

 ) as y on x.ID = y.note_id
 GROUP BY x.Agent_ID,
          x.Agent_Name,
          x.Tran_Year,
          x.Tran_Period,
          x.Original_Mobile_ID,
          x.Mobile_ID,
          x.Device_ID,
          x.New_Plan,
          x.Customer_Name,
          x.Device_Change_Date,
          x.New_Plan_Access_Charge,
          x.Model,
          x.Agent_SSO_ID,
          x.Customer_Type,
          x.Previous_Plan,
          x.Previous_Access_Charge,
          x.ID
```

More concisely, I would re-write it like this:

```
SELECT x.Agent_ID,
       x.Agent_Name,
       x.Tran_Year,
       x.Tran_Period,
       x.Original_Mobile_ID,
       x.Mobile_ID,
       x.Device_ID,
       x.New_Plan,
       x.Customer_Name,
       x.Device_Change_Date,
       x.New_Plan_Access_Charge,
       x.Model,
       x.Agent_SSO_ID,
       x.Customer_Type,
       x.Previous_Plan,
       x.Previous_Access_Charge,
       x.ID,
       y.all_notes
FROM vzw_missopportunity x
INNER JOIN locations l
    ON l.Outlet_ID = x.Agent_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT n.note_id,
           GROUP_CONCAT(n.note ORDER BY n.note_id separator " ") as all_notes
    FROM notes n
    GROUP BY n.note_id
) AS y
    ON y.note_id = x.ID
WHERE x.Agent_ID = "'.$_SESSION['agent'].'"
  AND l.district = "'.$_SESSION['district'].'"
```

Comment: Thank you @joshEller  This worked for me 100%.  Thank you so much